# _system_default_theme_features()

Tags: 7

I saw your post about getting this error "Fatal error: Call to undefined function _system_default_theme_features() in /home/depot/public_html/drupal/includes/theme.inc" after doing a Drupal upgrade.

How can I fix the error? The function is in the system.module file.  Errors after attempt upgrade on Drupal 7.

Drupal version 7

Comment: Which post? Which error? Please check your question to be more clear. This may help: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Hi, we are a community of over 30000 users. `Your post` is a bit vague, could you provide a link to the post? It might be of use.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Without more details, this is a duplicate of the other question, since you are asking what already asked from the other question: How do I fix it?